# Single login for Yii and Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, authentication, yii, single-sign-on

In a Yii app, I need to share userbase with Joomla installation. Registration needs to be done in Yii app. I have successfully done that. The issue is at login end. Yii app logs in fine when I comment out Joomla log in code but if I add call to Joomla login method, Yii app does not log in user. Authentication is successful but the session is not transferred to next pages. Following is my code

**LoginForm.php**

```
public function login()
{
    if($this->_identity===null)
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        $this->_identity->authenticate();
    }

    if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {
        $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
        JoomlaUsers::login($this->username, $this->password,$duration);
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
        var_dump(Yii::app()->user->isGuest);
        //Yii::app()->end();
        return true;
    }
    else
    return false;
}
```

**JoomlaUsers.php**

```
public static function login($username, $password,$remember)
{
    $mainframe = self::startIncludingJoomla();

    $credentials = array();
    $credentials['username'] = $username;
    $credentials['password'] = $password;

    //perform the login action
    $error = $mainframe->login($credentials,array('remember'=>$remember));
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    //now you are logged in
    self::endIncludingJoomla();
}


public static function startIncludingJoomla()
{

    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
    define('JPATH_BASE', Yii::app()->params['joomlaDir'] );
    define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

    spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase', 'autoload')); 
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');      
    $mainframe->initialise();
    return $mainframe;
}


public static function endIncludingJoomla()
{
    spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase', 'autoload')); 
}
```

In LoginForm.php, if I comment out following line, Yii app logs user in but user is not logged in to Joomla application. If I add that line login does not work for either of them

```
JoomlaUsers::login($this->username, $this->password,$duration);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the user table in DB is shared for yii and joomla? Both can use this?

Comment: No, the two applications have their own separate databases. I am accessing Joomla's database in my Yii application.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that Joomla was clearing session as its app was being created in following line of code

```
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

To achieve my desired result, I created a little Joomla component redirected to its URL and then from there redirected back to Yii application.